# Flutter android orientation stuck in landscape mode

Tags: android, flutter, screen-orientation

Since very recently the orientation of my Flutter app is hardstuck in landscape mode. At first there weren't any issues with the orientation. The only way to fix it currently, is by forcing portrait mode with

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);
```

However, this makes it impossible for the user to change the orientation (say on a tablet) to landscape mode.

What i already tried:

- I've already looked at my commit history to see if anything could've provoked this issue, but no luck there.
- Updating flutter to 2.0.4
- Running flutter doctor (no issues)

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867], locale de-CH)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.54.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

- Changing orientation in AndroidManifest.xml: `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"`
- When I log the current orientation it's still landscape at first, and then changes to portrait because of the settings from above.
  [Log from landscape -> portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD40X.png)

Thanks for any help in advance!
Bump, I'm still looking for an answer, unfortunately I didn't find anything until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to sumup Flutter package and what they have in their activity file.